# How to create an ad-hoc connection?

Tags: networking, arch-linux, wifi, networkmanager, connection-sharing

I need to make an adhoc connection on Archlinux (netbook used as a wifi repeater), I was using this tutorial to do it on Ubuntu :

> At the terminal install execute `sudo apt-get install dnsmasq-base` and then `sudo apt-get remove dnsmasq`
>
> Restart the NetworkManager by executing `sudo /etc/init.d/network-manager restart`
>
> Left-click on the NetworkManager icon and click "Create New Wireless Network"
>
> Name it "UbuntuAdhoc" and set the encryption to "WEP40"
>
> Connect PC2 using Ad-Hoc to the PC1

The main problem is `dnsmasq-mase` is missing but `dnsmasq` is present on Archlinux.

Here's what I found that could be helpful:

https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Dnsmasq
https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=6431

```
pacman -S dnsmasq
mkdir /etc/dnsmasq
mv /etc/resolv.conf /etc/dnsmasq
cd /etc
echo nameserver 127.0.0.1 > resolv.conf
mv rc.conf rc.conf.save 
sed  '/DAEMON/s/network/network dnsmasq.local/g' rc.conf.save>rc.conf
cd rc.d
sed  '/-z/s/dnsmasq/dnsmasq -r /etc/dnsmasq/resolv.conf /g' dnsmasq>dnsmasq.local
/etc/rc.d/dnsmasq.local start
/etc/rc.d/network restart
```

I have a problem with:

```
sed  '/-z/s/dnsmasq/dnsmasq -r /etc/dnsmasq/resolv.conf /g' dnsmasq>dnsmasq.local
```

It say that's the `../s/..` is not a known option.

It seems to have broken the `networkmanager` applet on xfce4. I blacklisted the dnsmasq stuff in `/etc/rc.conf`, it will be to repair in the progress, I can't use my wifi connection for now but my lan will do for now ...

I also checked about various ways of using a adhoc connection, as my girlfriend use my PC and I travel sometimes, I need a graphical way to make the adhoc connection.

I checked my favorite software `wicd` but it cannot make multiple connections and adhoc. It said that the version 2.0 maybe would but for now, the only alternative is `networkmanager`.

So, how I do it?

Comment: WEP? Seriously ? Ditch network-manager and use wpasupplicant directly like real men do, so you can use real WPA2 in ad-hoc mode.

Answer (score 2):

The `sed` command is broken (I guess people overlooked it somehow on the forum you refer to). It should be:

```
sed  '/-z/s:dnsmasq:dnsmasq -r /etc/dnsmasq/resolv.conf :g' dnsmasq>dnsmasq.local
```

The fact that you used that broken `sed` command resulted in erasing `/etc/rc.d/dnsmasq.local` (or creating it as an empty file). I don't know the details of how NetworkManager is configured on Ubuntu, but I'm guessing that the fact of `/etc/rc.d/dnsmasq.local` being empty can have an important impact on your whole network configuration.

You can either:

- Verify that `/etc/rc.d/dnsmasq.local` really is empty and if so, remove it - your network configuration should get back to the state at which it was before issuing that unfortunate `sed` command.
- `cd` into `` `/etc/rc.d/ `` and run the corrected `sed` command above. This should create the `dnsmasq.local` file containing what the author of [that forum post](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=6431) really intended. Possibly the rest might work after that.

Comment: Dnsmasq seem to work but I can't use NetworkManager to make my adhoc, it could be something else to do, I wonder what ...

Comment: Wiki pages most peoples tell me to try :

wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Ad-hoc_networking

https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Sharing_ppp_connection_with_wlan_interface

wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Software_Access_Point

The problem is they uses specific options for hardware mostly ...

Comment: They use such options because the possibility to use a card in ad-hoc mode **is** hardware-dependent (or rather *hardware-plus-driver-dependent*). If the command `iwconfig wlan0 mode Ad-Hoc` fails (assuming wlan0 is your card), then you will **not** be able to use ad-hoc mode with that card.

Comment: I was using it on ubuntu so it work ...